# Unable to store the value of IEnumerable of type in viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to store the result of the api call that returns results of type IEnumerable to a viewstate in my asp.net application. After executing line
this.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest = pendingChangeRequest , i see the value null in this.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest though the pendingChangeRequest contains value
What could be the problem ?

```
protected IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest> PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["UserChangeRequestsDataTable"] != null)
                {
                    return (IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest>)ViewState["PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest"];
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            set { ViewState["PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest"] = value; }
        }                






 var pendingChangeRequest =  Task.Run(async () => await service.GetPendingChangeRequest()).Result;
this.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest = pendingChangeRequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Albeit the real core problem is using ASP.NET Web Forms at all, your next underlying problem is using ViewState in your getter/setter implementations.

That is too much responsibility for a class property, and hides implementation magic from users of `PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest` property in the future.

What if another developer wants to use PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest property but not in an ASP.NET context and ViewState does not exist?

Simply declare your property for your class:

```
protected IEnumerable<string> PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest { get; set; }
```

Then use ViewState in the Service/Controller/Manager.:

```
var result =  Task.Run(async () => await service.GetPendingChangeRequest()).Result;
MyClass.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest = result; //examples setting the property
ViewState["PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest"] = result; //if you need to store the result for View to use
DisplayUserChangeRequestsData(result); //call the function you mentioned in your comments
```

This way you do not have to deal with the confusion of your getter/setter for hydrating/populating your ViewState key `"PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest"`.

This concept of an instance of a class persisting its own properties beyond its own instantiation in memory is an anti-pattern and you should be thinking about other components/mechanisms persisting the state of your class that contains the property "PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest". Why wouldn't you persist an instance of the class? Either way, a property worrying about its own persistence via ViewState or some other pattern is definitely a bad idea, buggy, confusing and wrought with design flaws and headaches.

Comment: But the problem is i need to pass this to method which is has the following signature   private void DisplayUserChangeRequestsData(IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest> pendingUserChangeRequest)

Comment: What does ViewState have to do with the argument you need to pass to DisplayUserChangeRequestsData?

Comment: The vaue stored in viewstate needs to be passed to that method. Or do i just pass the property name

Comment: What do you even need ViewState for?

Comment: I updated my answer to example calling DisplayUserChangeRequestsData function

Comment: This DisplayUserChangeRequestsData(result) works fine in the page load as soon as result is getting initialised but this.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest is null while trying to access in the sorting event of the grid

Comment: I did this to get it work  DisplayUserChangeRequestsData ((IEnumerable<PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest>) ViewState["PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest"]);

Comment: I wonder what is the use of setting the property like this this.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest = result; as this.PendingApprovalUserChangeRequest is null in the sorting method

Comment: Probably because of multiple HTTP requests. This fundamentally why you should be avoiding ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC Razor Views like the plague because obfuscates from you the basics of HTTP Requests/Responses and the stateless nature of web resources